# Does the Android Keystore make use of the Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) and Secure Element (SE) automatically if it is available?

Tags: android, security, mobile

Does the Android Keystore make use of the **Trusted Execution Environment (TEE)** and **Secure Element (SE)** automatically if it is available? Or are any further steps required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally yes.

There is no requirement for the Keystore to be hardware backed on all device, but if it *is* hardware backed and if that is by a TEE (the common case) then it will be used whenever Keystore backed keys are used.

See the current CDD document for requirements around this. Section [9.11. Keys and Credentials](https://source.android.com/compatibility/7.1/android-7.1-cdd#9_11_keys_and_credentials)

You may also find [this](https://doridori.github.io/android-security-the-forgetful-keystore/#comment-3256986772) answer interesting, as it talks about the `keymaster` & TEE implementations.

Comment: For Android 9 and above, whether SE & TEE can be supported together? Do we need to manually choose to SE (if available) or TEE (if available) through API. I think it cannot be chosen automatically (even if available) by OS, right?