# How to determine if an android application uses Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) and Secure Element (SE)?

Tags: android, security, drm, tee, ufs

I have gone through questions [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61225795/how-to-check-whether-android-phone-supports-tee/64422042#64422042) and [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957052/does-the-android-keystore-make-use-of-the-trusted-execution-environment-tee-an). But still I have an additional question.

How do we find out that an android application uses **Trusted Execution Environment** (TEE) and **Secure Element** (SE). Particularly a hardware backed environment.

Thanks